# What is the problem in sample spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring

I am fresher in spring mvc and I have developed one sample helloworld application but getting error during navigate one jsp page to another jsp page.

**Information provide when maven project create

[image]

**Project folder structure

[image]

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>practice1</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
     </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>practice1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

practice1-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.practice1.controller" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package com.practice1.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping("/helloworld")
    public ModelAndView hello() {
        String helloWorldMessage = "Hello world from practice1!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", helloWorldMessage); // 1st is view name 2nd is model name, 3rd is model Object
   }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.spring.practice1</groupId>
<artifactId>parctice1</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>practice1 Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>practice1</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <spring.version>5.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.36</mysql.version>
    <javax.version>3.1.0</javax.version>
    <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>HelloWorld</title>
  </head>
 <body>
   <a href="helloworld">Click here to read hello message </a>
 </body>
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>${message}
</body>
```

whenever click on the hyper link of index page to navigate to hello page getting bellow error. 
[image]

also eclipse console log like below;

INFO: Server startup in [10,576] milliseconds
Jan 26, 2020 11:12:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /practice1/helloworld

Comment: After updated the project folder structure and class path it's working find.

Answer (score -1):

You need to prepend context path to your links.

```
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

...
<a href="${contextPath}/helloworld">Click here to read hello message</a>
```